# install istio on GKE Autopilot 1.27.3-gke.100

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, autopilot

I have a GKE autpilot cluster in version `1.27.3-gke.100` and I want to install istio in it. The cluster was created without the tag `--workload-policies=allow-net-admin`. How do I enable it on an existing GKE cluster?

> [reference](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-security)
>
> NET_ADMIN for service meshes such as Istio: Specify --workload-policies=allow-net-admin in your cluster creation command. Available on new and upgraded existing clusters running GKE version 1.27 and later.

I believe it is the last piece of the puzzle before having a working (Istio + GKE) autopilot set-up.

In case that it might be of someone's help, here are the steps I've done so far and how I solved it, before arriving at the dead end described above.

- Download istioctl in my machine
- Istioctl install -y
- Kubectl apply -f samples/addons

FAIL 1: Looks like the Istio is asking to inject sidecars, but the traffic is lost. Open firewall rules

- gcloud compute firewall-rules update <cluster> --allow tcp:10250,tcp:443,tcp:15017

FAIL 2 (and current): New deployments are not creating anything. Looks like the ReplicaSet is failing with:

```
│   Warning  FailedCreate  6s (x17 over 5m36s)  replicaset-controller  Error creating: admission webhook "warden-validating.common-webhooks.networking.gke.io" denied the request: GKE Warden rejected the request be │
│ cause it violates one or more constraints.                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ Violations details: {"[denied by autogke-default-linux-capabilities]":["linux capability 'NET_ADMIN' on container 'istio-init' not allowed; Autopilot only allows the capabilities: 'AUDIT_WRITE,CHOWN,DAC_OVERRIDE │
│ ,FOWNER,FSETID,KILL,MKNOD,NET_BIND_SERVICE,NET_RAW,SETFCAP,SETGID,SETPCAP,SETUID,SYS_CHROOT,SYS_PTRACE'."]}                                                                                                         │
│ Requested by user: 'system:serviceaccount:kube-system:replicaset-controller', groups: 'system:serviceaccounts,system:serviceaccounts:kube-system,system:authenticated'.
```

- To grant NET_ADMIN, we need at leas 1.27 in the GKE cluster… Upgrade the cluster to `1.27.3-gke.100`. But the error persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Upgrading your GKE cluster to 1.27 run gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --workload-policies=allow-net-admin to enable the NET_ADMIN capability needed for Istio